# How can filter group id those have only single value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data and I need to filter group id those have only single `yes` value for column `category`.

```
data <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6),
category=c(NA,'no',NA,'yes',NA,'yes',NA,NA,'no',NA,'no','yes',NA,'no','yes','no','no',NA,'no',NA,'yes','no',NA,'yes','no',NA,'no','yes','no','yes'))
```

Expected output:

```
  id category
1  4       no
2  4     <NA>
3  4       no
4  4     <NA>
5  4      yes
6  5       no
7  5     <NA>
8  5      yes
9  5       no
```

I try it using

```
library(dplyr)
data1 <- data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter((cumsum(category == 'yes')<= 1), na.rm=TRUE) %>%
  ungroup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow your original approach with a minor edit:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(sum(category=="yes",na.rm=T)==1)
```

Output:

```
     id category
  <dbl> <chr>   
1     4 no      
2     4 NA      
3     4 no      
4     4 NA      
5     4 yes     
6     5 no      
7     5 NA      
8     5 yes     
9     5 no
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI, here is a base R approach:

```
#find counts for the yes/no
out<-table(data$category, data$id)

#extract the ids meeting the criteria
ids <- which(out["yes",]==1)

#Get the values
data[data$id %in% ids, ]
```